# Ultrasonic HC-SR04

Tags: hc-sr04

Having trouble with arduino
Ultrasonic Sensor  Module
HC-SR04
I'm sure when you read this you're going to say how stupid can he be and you're probably right but I'm 82 years old and I'm trying very hard. They say you're never too old to learn I hope they're right
This sensor model is driving me crazy I have tried and written two or three sketches and I cannot get it to work I know how simple it is for wires big deal but when I tried to read it through my serial monitor I get this a bunch of backward ? A C S A ? But the question are backwards . I have used two different boards new ones and tried three Ultrasonic Sensor hope you can help me thank you Dennis

Comment: you said absolutely nothing about the hardware, how it is connected, the program and the problem you are having

Comment: It sounds like an incorrect baud rate setting to me.

Comment: With such question please always include your code and your wiring. But I second Majenko with that it sounds like a wrong baudrate. In the Serial Monitor you need to select the same baudrate, that you used in your sketch with `Serial.begin()`.